# Long connection time at first attempt to join a lobby in Modern Warfare 2

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

On CoD:MW2 multiplayer I've noticed the connection time of my first attempt, right after a fresh restart of the game, is extremely long. Once I've connected to a lobby, the connection time is normal (the game instantly finds several possible lobbies to join).

My question is: does anyone else have this behavior?

If so, is there something I can do about it?

Comment: the game tries to synchronize with Infinity Ward servers to recall/upload game settings and other user stuff. That might be the reason why it's always stalling on start. There is nothing you can do about this, other than, well, moving to another continent or something like that.

Comment: Too bad I can't accept a comment as my answer :) Thanks, now I know at least why it's taking so damn long. However, I didn't had this behavior when I initially bought and played the game (right after release). Maybe it's due to an update?

Comment: Has always been like that. Sometimes it takes longer, sometimes you don't even see it doing it work. This is a comment since your question is not definitive enough. It can actually be anything. Are you on a PC?

Comment: I have the same issue. It takes forever to get into my first lobby, but nearly no time thereafter. The other thing I noticed is... My first lobby is always lag-free, but if I get moved to a different lobby, it's almost always laggy, even after multiple migrations. Nothing is more frustrating than waiting 10 minutes for the first lobby only to be joined to a lobby with a hacker.

Answer (score 3):

Do you see the ping number at the top right corner when its looking for a game?? The higher the number, the higher the lag/slower the connection will be.  Also if more than your Xbox360/PS3 is connected to your router, having other equipment utilize internet connection also will decrease your speed for your game.  Wireless tends to be less reliable than wired connection.  And if its PS3, games tend to fall more often than those on 360 (I have both and I can attest to that).  Check if you've got any of these factors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I'd suffered from a poor internet connection I would probably have it all the time. The strange thing is, the connection time is only on the first attempt very long (once I've managed to connect to a lobby, all consecutive connections run smooth). FYI I play it on a desktop with wired connection (not the biggest fan of wireless gaming here). I didn't include this information in my question as I'm pretty sure it's not my connection which is lagging (again, it would happen always, not just on the first attempt)

Comment: Hmmm interesting, I'd expect the PC version to be faster, but I remembered that now they don't even have dedicated servers for MW2.  So depending on your location and where the game is trying to look for a game, it may be a while until it finds and sticks to an acceptable connection.